# Sql distinct query returning same result with or with out Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm using 2 sql queries with to get distinct results but both the queries are returning same result.
here are the queries:

```
mysql> select count(distinct(device_id)) from device_desktops where created_at >="2018-09-17";
+----------------------------+
| count(distinct(device_id)) |
+----------------------------+
|                       3023 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.24 sec)

mysql> select count(distinct(device_id)) from device_desktops where created_at >="2018-09-17" and status="Pass";
+----------------------------+
| count(distinct(device_id)) |
+----------------------------+
|                       3023 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.25 sec)

mysql> select count(distinct(device_id)) from device_desktops where created_at >="2018-09-17" and status="Fail";
+----------------------------+
| count(distinct(device_id)) |
+----------------------------+
|                       1025 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

and this is the table structure:

```
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| device_id        | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| station          | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lower_limit      | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| flag             | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| test_description | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| actual_result    | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| upper_limit      | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time             | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| hw_id            | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| test_type        | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| test_id          | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status           | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| misc             | varchar(191)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at       | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at       | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why it is returning same result in first and second queries at top,
while the 3rd query returns different result..
what is the mistake in my query.
Any help will be appreciated..

i tried also this query:

```
mysql> select count(distinct device_id ) from device_desktops where created_at >="2018-09-17" group by status;
+----------------------------+
| count(distinct device_id ) |
+----------------------------+
|                       1025 |
|                        119 |
|                       3023 |
+----------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.46 sec)
```

i also tried this query without distinct:

```
mysql> select count(device_id) from device_desktops where created_at >="2018-09-17";
+------------------+
| count(device_id) |
+------------------+
|            64744 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)

mysql> select count(device_id) from device_desktops where created_at >="2018-09-17" and status="Fail";
+------------------+
| count(device_id) |
+------------------+
|             3628 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)

mysql> select count(device_id) from device_desktops where created_at >="2018-09-17" and status="Pass";
+------------------+
| count(device_id) |
+------------------+
|            60964 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)
```

Comment: Perhaps the data itself that meets the date criteria also has a status of Pass in both cases. So even if you put just the date part, perhaps those rows if you look at the status they will say pass.

Comment: @arahman it is not possible suppose if there are total 3023 devices from the date till now then how it is counting fail?? whose result is totally different.
if we combine 3023 +  1025 that is = 4048..
but this query says there are only 3023 devices out if which 1025 gas result of fail

Comment: as @arahman stated all "passed" for that date could have a failed status aswell, could you insert a new entry with a new `device_id` and status Pass ?

Comment: @SalmanZafar Are you saying that if you execute this query `select count(distinct(device_id)) from device_desktops` you will get back `3023` rows returned from the query?

Comment: @SalmanZafar `device_id = 10, status = "Pass"; device_id = 10, status = "Fail"` a `DISTINCT(device_id) = 1`

Comment: @arahman yup...

Comment: @SalmanZafar How about you do a check in the count for status type before hand. `select count( (case when status = 'Pass' then 1 else NULL end) ) from device_desktops where created_at >="2018-09-17";
` and same for the other `when status = 'Fail'`.

Comment: If device_id is a natural key, then there will only be one.

Comment: When you understand this query, you will understand your problem: `SELECT device_id FROM device_desktops WHERE created_at >="2018-09-17" GROUP BY device_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT status) > 1;`

Comment: @Cid i just inserted new row with the status of pass and different device_id it is still returning 3024 and 3024 with or with out where

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function... Remove the redundant parentheses to make code clearer, i.e. `select count(distinct device_id) from device_desktops...`.

Comment: @SalmanZafar It would be easier if you had some sample rows from the actual table data, that way we could see properly the way the data is presented.

Comment: (1,pass),(1,fail) -> count(distinct id) = 1...

Comment: @PhamX.Bach now it is returning 1100 rows of device_id

Comment: i just updated my question with one more query i just exectued

Comment: On a sidenote: The SQL string delimiter is the single quote, not the double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `status='pass'` for all the devices, and you have  `status='fail'` for 1025 of them, the result is ok, because you have used `distinct`. Try without using `distinct` and you will see that the number of all devices will be the sum of devices that pass and devices that fail and the devices that may have another status( possibly null or empty ).

Example:

- You have devices 1, 2.
- Both those devices have a row with status='pass'
- Device 1 has a row with status='fail'

Result:

- The 1st query will return both devices.
- 2nd query returns both devices.
- 3rd query returns only device one.

If you removed distinct, you would have respectively 3,2,1 rows for each query

Comment: Good explanation.

Comment: hi,thanks for the answer i just aedited my question and added three queries i just executed the total device_id's = 64744 while with status pass = 60964 and with status fail = 3628.so 3628 + 60964 = 64592 while total device_id's are 64744

Comment: use a query select * from device_desktops where created_at >="2018-09-17" and status not in ("Pass","Fail") and you should have records with  another status (empty, null, or sth else)

Comment: yes you are right..
how should is get distinct count of total devices?
i need to get the distinct/unique count of all devices from date 2018-09-17

Comment: Your first query does it.

Comment: Thanks mate for the answer :)

Comment: happy to help :D

Answer (score 0):

This is your data:

1. There are 3023 different device IDs in the table.
2. For 3023 device IDs there exist one or more records with status 'Pass'
3. For 1025 device IDs there exist one or more records with status 'Fail'
4. For 119 device IDs there exist one or more records with another status (maybe NULL).

I think that's rather obvious :-)